# Vertex AI automatic retraining

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, mlops

I’m trying to create a Vertex AI endpoint with Monitoring enabled that can trigger a Vertex AI pipeline execution when one of the deployed models drops its performance.
However, Vertex AI does not provide any built-in feature to do it.
Is there a method to capture the alert thrown by Vertex AI Monitoring and trigger the Pipeline?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think the author cannot add code to reproduce the problem. Because the question is related to visual components of Vertex AI.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about your use case, could you share a code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Vertex AI Model Monitoring jobs are logged as part of Cloud Logging [1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-monitoring/using-model-monitoring#cloud-logging-info).
2. You can react to those loggings using log-based alerts [2](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts). For that, you need to configure a notification channel to PubSub [3](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.notificationChannels#NotificationChannel)
3. Based on those PubSub message you can trigger a Cloud Function [4](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)
4. The Cloud Function can initiate the Vertex AI Pipeline run to re-train the model [5](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.pipelineJobs/create)

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-monitoring/using-model-monitoring#cloud-logging-info

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.notificationChannels#NotificationChannel

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.pipelineJobs/create